# /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg has all configurations commented out. How is ansible working?

Tags: configuration, automation

for background and context:  I'm a network engineer by trade, and I did not come up through the traditional "systems" or "IT" path in my career, but now I'm working on learning network automation and orchestration for configuration management and support. before I move on to using, in this case, ansible, to actually automate my base configuration plays for new router/switch deployments, I want to understand fully what is happening on my control station in terms of ansible code interacting with system configurations and the like.
with all of that in mind.....

```
$ cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)"
[defaults]
[inventory]
[privilege_escalation]
[paramiko_connection]
[ssh_connection]
[persistent_connection]
[accelerate]
[selinux]
[colors]
[diff]

$ cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg | more

[defaults]

# some basic default values...

#inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts--------------->commented out?
#library        = /usr/share/my_modules/
#module_utils   = /usr/share/my_module_utils/
#remote_tmp     = ~/.ansible/tmp
#local_tmp      = ~/.ansible/tmp
#forks          = 5
#poll_interval  = 15
#sudo_user      = root
#ask_sudo_pass = True
#ask_pass      = True
#transport      = smart
#remote_port    = 22
#module_lang    = C
#module_set_locale = False

$ ansible-playbook test.yaml --connection=localhost
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: all

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Ansible is working!"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Obviously, when I run the playbook, ansible is reading /etc/ansible/hosts, find no data, and falling back to localhost, but how does ansible know to read this file if the default configuration is commented out?  what am I missing?

Comment: Silly me.  The settings are stored in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible-2.0.0.2-py2.7.egg/ansible/constants.py`

Comment: hmmm......I don't have an ansible package located in my dist-packages distro.  not sure if my running the ubuntu subsystem on windows changes how software packages install.  I have the latest python and ansible releases installed....

Answer (score 2):

The parameters are built into the app until you uncomment them to change them.  From the top of the config file:

```
# nearly all parameters can be overridden in ansible-playbook 
# or with command line flags. ansible will read ANSIBLE_CONFIG,
# ansible.cfg in the current working directory, .ansible.cfg in
# the home directory or /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg, whichever it
# finds first
```

I ran a test on my system with it.

*First, no changes to the `.cfg` file:*

```
~$ ansible
Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]

Options:
  -a MODULE_ARGS, --args=MODULE_ARGS
                        module arguments
  --ask-become-pass     ask for privilege escalation password
  -k, --ask-pass        ask for connection password
  --ask-su-pass         ask for su password (deprecated, use become)
  -K, --ask-sudo-pass   ask for sudo password (deprecated, use become)
  --ask-vault-pass      ask for vault password
  -B SECONDS, --background=SECONDS
                        run asynchronously, failing after X seconds
                        (default=N/A)
  -b, --become          run operations with become (nopasswd implied)
  --become-method=BECOME_METHOD
                        privilege escalation method to use (default=sudo),
                        valid choices: [ sudo | su | pbrun | pfexec | runas |
                        doas ]
  --become-user=BECOME_USER
                        run operations as this user (default=root)
  -C, --check           don't make any changes; instead, try to predict some
                        of the changes that may occur
  -c CONNECTION, --connection=CONNECTION
                        connection type to use (default=smart)
  -D, --diff            when changing (small) files and templates, show the
                        differences in those files; works great with --check
  -e EXTRA_VARS, --extra-vars=EXTRA_VARS
                        set additional variables as key=value or YAML/JSON
  -f FORKS, --forks=FORKS
                        specify number of parallel processes to use
                        (default=5)
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host path
                        (default=/etc/ansible/hosts) or comma separated host
                        list
  -l SUBSET, --limit=SUBSET
                        further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern
  --list-hosts          outputs a list of matching hosts; does not execute
                        anything else
  -m MODULE_NAME, --module-name=MODULE_NAME
                        module name to execute (default=command)
  -M MODULE_PATH, --module-path=MODULE_PATH
                        specify path(s) to module library (default=None)
  --new-vault-password-file=NEW_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE
                        new vault password file for rekey
  -o, --one-line        condense output
  --output=OUTPUT_FILE  output file name for encrypt or decrypt; use - for
                        stdout
  -P POLL_INTERVAL, --poll=POLL_INTERVAL
                        set the poll interval if using -B (default=15)
  --private-key=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, --key-file=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
                        use this file to authenticate the connection
  --scp-extra-args=SCP_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to scp only (e.g. -l)
  --sftp-extra-args=SFTP_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to sftp only (e.g. -f,
                        -l)
  --ssh-common-args=SSH_COMMON_ARGS
                        specify common arguments to pass to sftp/scp/ssh (e.g.
                        ProxyCommand)
  --ssh-extra-args=SSH_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to ssh only (e.g. -R)
  -S, --su              run operations with su (deprecated, use become)
  -R SU_USER, --su-user=SU_USER
                        run operations with su as this user (default=root)
                        (deprecated, use become)
  -s, --sudo            run operations with sudo (nopasswd) (deprecated, use
                        become)
  -U SUDO_USER, --sudo-user=SUDO_USER
                        desired sudo user (default=root) (deprecated, use
                        become)
  --syntax-check        perform a syntax check on the playbook, but do not
                        execute it
  -T TIMEOUT, --timeout=TIMEOUT
                        override the connection timeout in seconds
                        (default=10)
  -t TREE, --tree=TREE  log output to this directory
  -u REMOTE_USER, --user=REMOTE_USER
                        connect as this user (default=None)
  --vault-password-file=VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE
                        vault password file
  -v, --verbose         verbose mode (-vvv for more, -vvvv to enable
                        connection debugging)
  --version             show program's version number and exit
ERROR! Missing target hosts
```

*Now, uncommenting the line `#log_path = /var/log/ansible.log`:*

```
~$ ansible
[WARNING]: log file at /var/log/ansible.log is not writeable, aborting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 40, in <module>
    from ansible.utils.display import Display
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/utils/display.py", line 57, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(filename=path, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1547, in basicConfig
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 913, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 943, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/ansible.log'
```

So, as I can see, all of the settings are built in until you make a change to the file to override it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Terrance, thanks for the info! definitely helpful.  I know the question appears to be an ansible question, but really....it was a linux question with an ansible "cloak" ;)  when you say the parameters are "built into the app", you are referring to the ansible program that runs on /usr/bin/python?  are these parameters simply imported from a shared library then?  I hope I'm not asking stupid questions....

Comment: @Net_Warrior Nope, not a stupid question.  Unfortunately, I don' t know the answer to that one as who ever writes the application can have full control over how they do it.  Some writers might just have it read the `.cfg` where others have it all built in hiding it somewhere.  It is all hit and miss.  I wish I knew a solid answer for you on that one.

Comment: @Net_Warrior I guess you could always download the source for the application and see if it gets compiled in the application.  I have done that before with the `scrub` application to change the types of passes when scrubbing a hard drive.

Comment: I get it...thanks for the help.  at least I have something to go on that make sense to me now.  clearly, ansible, as with any software package, obviously works just by virtue of installing the software.  if it didn't, no one would use it ;), but it's always better to know the 0's and 1's.  thanks again for the help on this one!